# safari react-parallax-tilt bug

Tags: html, css, reactjs, safari

I have strange bug only in safari

my header container have position: sticky and when I hover items wrapped in Tilt component and scroll page down this [bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3anF.gif) happens

I already tried different z-index and add custom containers and nothing did not help me

Also make a simple sandbox with this bug
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-haze-x9ohn5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer by myself. need to put
`transform: translateZ(100px);`
to your header block